# 12V blade fuse box type of connectors - identification

Tags: connector, identification, fuses

I have a following appliance (blade) fuse box:

[image: blade fuse box]

1) How these four connectors are called? Do they have a name?

2) What is the best way to connect a cable to it without soldering such that the wire is tied down and won't move around?

I can't find any specification for the product with the answers for above. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as **Faston** (that's a trademark), **tab**, **quick disconnect**, **spade** or **blade** terminals.  These are all names for the same thing, but there are different sizes - make sure you have the right tab width and thickness. These are probably 1/4" wide and 0.8mm thick. You want a matching female connector, and these are normally joined to wire by crimping.

The associated terminals normally come in three wire sizes, with red (small), blue, and yellow (large) insulation. They cost pennies, and you can buy assortment kits. Make sure you have the right size for the wire you're using, or it won't stay put.  Really, you ought to crimp it on with a special tool costing £10-100 depending on quality. You can do it with pliers, but its very hard to make it reliable.